# How can I login to git on a Heroku worker dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, worker

I'm currently making a rails project that initializes, adds, commits and pushes temporary folders in a heroku application. I have a worker that uses the tilde syntax to `git init`, `git add .` and so forth but it won't allow me to push anything unless I'm logged in, which I can't do since this is an automated process.

In development, I just logged in with my credentials when prompted and it saved my credentials, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in production(heroku specifically).

How can I do this in Heroku?
Thanks!

The error message I get

```
*** Please tell me who you are.
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579213+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579214+00:00 app[worker.1]: Run
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579235+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579236+00:00 app[worker.1]:   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579237+00:00 app[worker.1]:   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579237+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579238+00:00 app[worker.1]: to set your account's default identity.
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579238+00:00 app[worker.1]: Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579239+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-05-31T00:14:48.579244+00:00 app[worker.1]: fatal: empty ident name (for <omitted.(none)>) not allowed
2016-05-31T00:14:48.627233+00:00 app[worker.1]: Host key verification failed.
2016-05-31T00:14:48.627836+00:00 app[worker.1]: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
2016-05-31T00:14:48.627842+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-05-31T00:14:48.627843+00:00 app[worker.1]: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using GitHub as well as Git, you will need to generated a token for your account.

[Creating an access token for command-line use](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/)

Once you have the token, you would use the token in place of your password. The token is equivalent to a password, so you will need to take proper precautions. I would suggest storing the token in your Heroku environment.

You would now clone the repo using your username and token, like so:

`git clone https://<MYUSERNAME>:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/rails/rails.git`

You should now be able to `git push` back to GitHub.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  What if I'm initializing and pushing without cloning?  My heroku app creates a folder with a bunch of files, initializes the new folder, adds everything, commits and pushes it to a repository that i have created earlier.

Comment: I found `git config --global credential.helper cache` with the timeout option. Is there a way to make the infinite? And would that be carried over to other heroku dynos of the same app?